# Find out whether PyQt QPushButton is checked using self.sender()

Tags: python, python-2.7, qt, pyqt

The `QPushButton` `lightsBtn` is a toggle button that switches a light on and off. When the user presses `lightsBtn`, the function `lightsBtnHandler` will check whether the button is currently checked or not and calls either `turnOnLights` or `turnOffLights`.

I think `self.sender()` is able to access properties of the `QPushButton`, but I cant find any documentation on accessing the checked state.

Is it possible?

```
class Screen(QMainWindow):

    def initUI(self):
        lightsBtn= QPushButton('Turn On')
        lightsBtn.setCheckable(True)  
        lightsBtn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton:checked {color: white; background-color: green;}")
        lightsBtn.clicked.connect(self.lightsBtnHandler)
        lightsBtn.show()

    def lightsBtnHandler(self):
        if self.sender().?? isChecked():    # How to check for checked state?
            self.turnOnLights()
        else:
            self.turnOffLights()
```

Comment: Maybe change `lightsBtn` to `self.lightsBtn` and then the condition is just `if self.lightsBtn.isChecked():`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

following the @Matho comment I have modified your code a little bit.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton
import sys

class Screen(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Screen, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.lightsBtn= QPushButton('Turn On')
        self.lightsBtn.setCheckable(True)  
        self.lightsBtn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton:checked {color: white; background-color: green;}")
        self.lightsBtn.clicked.connect(self.lightsBtnHandler)

        # probaply you will want to set self.lightsBtn 
        # at certain spot using layouts
        self.setCentralWidget(self.lightsBtn)

    def lightsBtnHandler(self):
        if self.lightsBtn.isChecked():
            self.turnOnLights()
        else:
            self.turnOffLights()

    def turnOnLights(self):
        print("truned on")

    def turnOffLights(self):
        print("truned off")

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Screen()
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```